# How does this gitignore regex work "*,cover"

Tags: git, gitignore

The [python .gitinore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) provided by GitHub has the following regex,

```
*,cover
```

on [line 49](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore#L49).

What exactly does this regex mean? Is it, "anything, then a comma, then the word `cover`"?

Comment: I had a try and a file named `,cover` or `hello,cover` was ignored. But I have no idea why a file has a name like xxx,cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a typo. Fixed now with following PR.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2379

Answer (score 2):

It's not a regex, but a wildcard. In regex (regular expressions), `*` means "repeated as many times as you want", and comes as a postfix operator. In wildcards, `*` means, as you guessed, "anything".

Answer (score 2):

I have also seen this as `*.py,cover` to ignore files created by the [AnnotateReporter](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/master/coverage/annotate.py) of [Coverage.py](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy) that have the file extension `.py,cover` - the comma is not a typo here and also not part of the wildcard syntax, it's just a literal comma.